# For all $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}(=:A)\otimes_R K)$, ($\pi \cdot 1_A) \otimes_R 1_K \notin \mathfrak{p}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:X\to \operatorname{Spec}R$ be a morpism to a spectrum of a discrete valuation ring. Let $\pi \in R$ be a uniformizaer. Let $K:=\operatorname{Frac}R$. Let $x\in X$ and $A:= \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

First, Note that Alex Youcis commented below, there is a $R$-algebra structure ( ring homomorphism ) $R  \to A$, induced from $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) \to X \to \operatorname{Spec}R$.

Now, **my question is**, for all prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_R K)$, $\pi \cdot 1_A \notin 
 ^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p})$, where $ ^{a}\iota : \operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_R K) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is the induced morphism from the canonical morphism $\iota : A \to A \otimes_R K$ ? Or equivalently, does $(\pi \cdot 1_A ) \otimes_R 1_K$ not contained in $\mathfrak{p}$?

This question originates from the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of the Proposition 14.16 :

> Proposition 14.16. Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring, let $s$ be the special and $\eta$ the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec}R$. Let $f:X\to \operatorname{Spec}R$ be a morphism. Assume that $X$ is locally noetherian. Suppose that all maximal points of the special fiber $f^{-1}(s)$ lie in the closure of $f^{-1}(\eta)$ and that the special fiber $f^{-1}(s)$ is reduced. Then $X$ is flat over $R$.

C.f. In his book p.427, he noted that "Assume moreover that $Y= \operatorname{Spec}R$ for a discrete valuation ring $R$.Then $X$ is flat over $Y$ if and only if for all open affine subschemes $U$ the $R$-module $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ has no $\pi$-torsion, where $\pi$ is a uniformizing element."

His proof of the Proposition 14.16 is as follows :

***Proof.*** Let $\pi$ be a uniformizing element of $R$. It is enough to show that for all $x\in X$, writing $A=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, $\pi$ is a regular element of $A$. Let $a\in A$ with $\pi^{i}a=0$ for some $i>0$. We want to show that $a=0$. Certainly $f^{-1}(\eta) = \operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes_R K)$ is contained in $V(a)$, because **its points are prime ideals which do not contain $\pi$**. And.. ( omission of next step of proof ; If needed, I'll upload full proof )

( C.f. Possible errata : For the $f^{-1}(\eta)$ in the proof, more correct notation is $f_1^{-1}(\eta)$, where $f_1 : \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to X \to \operatorname{Spec}R$ is the composition. )

I don't understand why the bolded statement is true. My rough understanding is as follows :

First, note that the projection map $\operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_R K) \to \operatorname{Spec}A$ is induced by the canonical morphism $\iota : A \to A\otimes_R K$. In the proof of the Proposition 14.16, we want to show that $^{a}\iota(\operatorname{Spec}A\otimes_R K) \subseteq V(a)$. Let $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_R K)$. Then $^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p})$ is a prime ideal of $A$. Note that $\pi^{i}a= (\pi^{i}\cdot 1_A) \cdot a = 0 \in\ ^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p})$ as in the proof.
So if $\pi \cdot 1_A \notin\  ^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p})$, then $ a \in\ ^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p}) $. So, $^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p}) \in V(a)$. And is $\pi \cdot 1_A \notin\  ^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p})$ ture? $\pi \cdot 1_A$ is unit of $A$? If so, why?

Can anyone help?

Comment: For Q1: is there not a map $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\to X\to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$? For Q2, as $\pi$ is a unit in $K$ if $\pi$ was contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ then $\mathfrak{p}=(1)$ which is not possible.

Comment: @Alex Youcis : O.K. I want to discuss this issue in more detail with you. First, note that the projection map $\operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_R K) \to \operatorname{Spec}A$ is induced by the canonical morphism $\iota : A \to A\otimes_R K$. As in the proof in the Proposition 14.16, we want to show that $^{a}\iota(\operatorname{Spec}A\otimes_R K) \subseteq V(a)$. Let $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_R K)$. Then $^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p})$ is a prime ideal of $A$. Note that $\pi^{i}a= (\pi^{i}\cdot 1_A) \cdot a = 0 \in ^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p})$ as in the proof.

Comment: So if $\pi \cdot 1_A \notin  ^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p})$, then $ a \in ^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p}) $. So, $^{a}\iota(\mathfrak{p}) \in V(a)$. And is it ture? $\pi \cdot 1_A$ is unit of $A$? If so, why?

Comment: I am not saying that $\pi$ is a unit of $A$, but as it is a unit of $K$ it is a unit of $A\otimes_R K$.

Comment: O.K. Perhaps, you mean $(\pi \cdot 1_A) \otimes_R 1_K = 1_A \otimes_R (\pi \cdot 1_K) = 1_A \otimes_R \frac{\pi}{1}$, which is an unit of $A \otimes_R K$?

Comment: @Alex Youcis : Uhm..Why the uniformizing element $\pi$ is unit in $K$?

Comment: I think there might be a slight disconnect here. You should probably think about that for a few minutes.

Comment: @Alex Youcis : Yes, I guess that since the DVR $R$ is not a field, its maximal ideal is nonzero, so $\pi$ is nonzero, so $\frac{\pi}{1}$ is unit in $K := \operatorname{Frac}R$. Is it true?

Comment: Yes. $\text{   }$

Comment: @Alex Youcis : Thanks  :) ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $(\pi \cdot 1_A) \otimes_R 1_K$ is not contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ since, by noting that $(\pi \cdot 1_A) \otimes_R 1_K = 1_A \otimes_R ( \pi \cdot 1_K) = 1_A \otimes_R (\frac{\pi}{1})$ and $\frac{\pi}{1}$ is unit in $K:= \operatorname{Frac}R$
( $\because$ Since the DVR $R$ is not a field by the definition, its maximal ideal is nonzero so that its uniformizaer $\pi$ is also nonzero. So $\frac{\pi}{1}$ is unit in $K:=\operatorname{Frac}R$), so that $1_A \otimes_R (\frac{\pi}{1})$ is unit in $A\otimes_RK$, which should not be contained in $\mathfrak{p}$.